# Errors in dynamic range in combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried everything and looked trough forums but have not found a solution.

Tried all this versions that are commented out. Sometimes it would work but only if I have the "data" sheet open, but if I am on the Sheet1 it would show error and won't work.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


    MultiPage1.Value = 0
    'Call ComboBox

     'Category = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Address
     'ComboBox1.RowSource = Worksheets("data").Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Address
     'ComboBox2.RowSource = Sheet2.Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Address

     'Worksheets("data")


    ' Add array to combobox
    ComboBox1.List = Sheet2.Range("A1:A7").Value


    ' Set the first item in combobox
    'ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
    'ComboBox2.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
With Worksheets("data")
    ComboBox1.List = .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value
End With
```

In your posted examples you have unqualified `Range()` references, which by default point to the ActiveSheet

Comment: OMG, thank you. I spent hours and hours trying to figure this out, can't believe it's so simple. I am quite new to the excel vba, so a lot of the things are not quite apparent right away.